# DeckLayoutPanel not displaying below banner

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a simple GWT app with a top level UI configured with UiBinder like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui = 'urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g = 'urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainApplicationWidget" styleName="main-panel">
      <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div class="banner">
          <div class="banner-text-left">
            <h3>Some H3 Text</h3>
            <h2>Some H2 Text</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </g:HTMLPanel>

      <g:DeckLayoutPanel ui:field="deckLayoutPanel" styleName="main-deck">
      </g:DeckLayoutPanel>
    </g:FlowPanel>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The CSS is:

```
.banner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/blue-banner.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}
.banner h2 {
    font-size:  60px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", "Helvetica";
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-align: right;
}
.banner h3 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", "Helvetica";
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}
.banner-text-left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.main-deck {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The code inserts this simple panel into the DeckLayoutView:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui = 'urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g = 'urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <center>
      <h1>Test Placeholder</h1>
      <g:Label ui:field="testLabel" text="Test"/>
    </center>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

When I run the app in devmode, I see the banner and the two text strings, but no DeckLayoutView.  How do I get that to appear?

Answer (score 1):

You can not see the `DeckLayoutPanel` because it hides its children.

See documentation on [DeckLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.html):

> Once a widget has been added to a DeckPanel, its **visibility**, width, and height attributes will be manipulated.

Simply, the `DeckLayoutPanel` will call `setVisible(false)` on the widget that you are adding.

This is because

> *(...)* only one *(widget)* can be visible at a time

What you should do is to call one of those methods on your `DeckLayoutPanel` instance:

```
public void showWidget(int index)
public void showWidget(Widget widget)
```

---

Also, make sure that the `DeckLayoutPanel`'s height is not 0. `DeckLayoutPanel` implements [RequiresResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html), which means that it needs to be explicity sized.

> Widgets that implement this interface should only be added to those that implement [`ProvidesResize`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html).

Comment: Here's my code:   public void onModuleLoad()
    {
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
      {
        public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e)
          {
          InfoDialog dialog = new InfoDialog("Uncaught:  " + e);
          dialog.show();
          }
      });
    
    
    deckLayoutPanel.add(testPanel_);
    deckLayoutPanel.showWidget(testPanel_);

    RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    root.add(mainApplicationWidget);
    }
Why would the height be 0?  Shouldn't GWT set it to whatever it needs to show TestPanel?

Comment: Hmm, there's no way to format comments?  I hope the code is short enough to be clear.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include info about `RequiresResize` interface. That would explain 0 height.

Comment: I think the second half is perhaps more important than the first - HTMLPanel isn't a ProvidesResize, and without more detail, we can't tell if the parent of HTMLPanel is either (and chances are the widget that the UiBinder is mapped to doesn't correctly pass on the resize anyway - IsWidget will, Widget or Composite won't unless you expressly implement RequiresResize).

Comment: I wrapped both the HTMLPanels in SimpleLayoutPanels, but no joy.  This seems like a very common layout pattern -- is there documentation anywhere that shows how to do it?  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to achieve, but you might find [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) (notice Dock vs Deck) interesting: _A panel that lays its child widgets out "docked" at its outer edges, and allows its last widget to take up the remaining space in its center._

Comment: I want a simple page with two divs.  The first one contains an image and some text, the second contains the DeckLayoutPanel where I load the rest of my application.  I switched the UI.ui.xml to use a DockLayoutPanel with the image and text in north and the DeckLayoutPanel in center.  That required me to specify a size for north, which is inelegant.  More importantly, it now fails with the error "This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets." but doesn't tell me which widget it is complaining about.

Comment: The trick seems to be that I have to wrap the DockLayoutPanel in a FlowPanel to get rid of the "does not implement HasWidgets" exception.  Now it displays the way I intend, but I'm still unhappy with having to specify an explicit size for the north panel.  I'd like to understand why the original version doesn't work.

Comment: Putting a `RequiresResize` child in a non-`ProvidesResize` parent like FlowPanel will result in it failing to get sizes correctly. That goes for the parent then too - using `SimpleLayoutPanel` doesn't as a parent is great, as long as you put `SimpleLayoutPanel` in a `ProvidesResize`... or it in turn won't get sizes. Built-in root layout panels are `ResizeLayoutPanel` (which needs to be given a size via CSS or whatever), or `RootLayoutPanel` (which must be the root of your whole page). Beyond that, you have to correctly call the resize methods yourself.